# If function giving me problems

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

My value keeps becoming false instead of the values i've added even when i enter Male. anyone has any idea?

```
If gender = "Male" Then
Sheet2.Range("A2").Value = "he" & Sheet2.Range("A3").Value = "him" & Sheet2.Range("A4").Value = "his"
Else
Sheet2.Range("A2").Value = "she" & Sheet2.Range("A3").Value = "her" & Sheet2.Range("A4").Value = "her"
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign a value two time in the same statement. Any = character after the first is treated as a logical operator (is equal to), not as an assignment.

So if you have:

```
a = b = c
```

VBA treats the statement as: Assign to A the results of "Is b equal to c".
It gets more complicated if you have three equal signs in a statement, but it won't be what you want in any rate.

Additionally, the & operator is for string concatenation. so

```
a = "top" & "hat"
```

will assign the string "tophat" to a.

You might want to use the : operator instead of &. That separates statements on a single line. So try this:

```
If gender = "Male" Then
Sheet2.Range("A2").Value = "he" : Sheet2.Range("A3").Value = "him" : Sheet2.Range("A4").Value = "his"
Else
Sheet2.Range("A2").Value = "she" : Sheet2.Range("A3").Value = "her" : Sheet2.Range("A4").Value = "her"
End If
```

However, I would urge you not to use : here. There's really no need, and I think it makes the code harder to read. I'd suggest:

```
If gender = "Male" Then
    Sheet2.Range("A2").Value = "he"  
    Sheet2.Range("A3").Value = "him"
    Sheet2.Range("A4").Value = "his"
Else
    Sheet2.Range("A2").Value = "she"
    Sheet2.Range("A3").Value = "her"  
    Sheet2.Range("A4").Value = "her"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Rich Holton gave you the reason why your code didn't work

Here I propose you some different techniques

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim valsArray As Variant '<--| declare a Variant variable to hold an array
    Dim gender As String

    gender = "Male" '<--| gender initialization for testing purposes

    If gender = "Male" Then
        valsArray = Array("he", "him", "his") '<--| fill your Variant with values corresponding to the 'gende'r value
    Else
        valsArray = Array("she", "her", "her") '<--| fill your Variant with values corresponding to the 'gende'r value
    End If
    Sheet2.Range("A2:A4").Value = Application.Transpose(valsArray) '<--| write all values in one shot (you need 'Transpose()' to change the "horizontal" Variant array to a "vertical" one and fit the range you're fill values of        
End Sub
```

---

you can also shorten it down even more by using `IIf()` function:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim gender As String

    gender = "Male" '<--| gender initialization for testing purposes

    Sheet2.Range("A2:A4").Value = Application.Transpose(IIf(gender = "Male", Array("he", "him", "his"), Array("she", "her", "her")))        
End Sub
```

Comment: The poor lad/lass is clearly fairly new at this. ;-) Probably not up for your advanced techniques -- which are cool, by the way.

Comment: @RichHolton, you get "advanced" by trying at advancing... I threw in some comments but if OP needs some more explanation, he can ask for them. however he can run that code in break mode and step through it by clicking F8 while in your VBA IDE, and using Immediate Window (CTRL+G to pop it out) to query relevant variables ore expressions (i.e. type `? Sheet2.Range("A2:A4").Address` and press return to see the outcome)

Comment: Thanks guys! all great suggestions! I've got it done! Would've have done it without you guys!